# Adding Taxonomy terms programmatically with specific tid?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I would like to add a term to a vocabulary specifing the **tid**, already tried with [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) and [Taxonomy import/export via XML](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml) modules but both create terms with a new tid.

I even tried programmatically with *[taxonomy_term_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7)* but if i set the **tid** it just looks for a term with that ID.

I need to do this because then i'll import a lot of nodes, and all of them already have a relation with a term.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tid** will be assigned to the terms automatically by drupal. My suggestion is first create the terms then you can use **[taxonomy_get_term_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7)** function to find the term and then map it to the respective node while importing.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a custom number field to you taxonomy vocabulary, and save this reference id there for later use.